# Building a website that interacts with DB and/or XML

Tags: python, perl

I'm looking to get into web development.  My goal is to create some interactive webpages that interact with MS SQL databases (read/insert/updates), and also possibly sites that interact with XML files.

I've got some basic understanding of Python and Perl scripting.  Can someone point me in the right direction in either of those languages to accomplish what i'm looking to do, or if it's easier to accomplish in another language what would that be?

Apologies if my stated goal is too broad.

Comment: Both lanuages are fine. Pick any webframework, read some tutorials, and start coding! (If you choose the Perl stack, I'd suggest investigating Dancer for the app, a DBI driver for the db, and XML::LibXML for XML handling). Python has equivalent libs. However, recommending specific tools is off topic for stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd strongly suggest you to look into some of the web development frameworks. They take care of many low-level tasks which is needed in order to build a solid web page. I'm not very familiar with perl, so I can only suggest Python frameworks, especially one of the my favourites - [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/). It has very good documentation which is essential for the first-timer. I believe you should be fine as long as you follow the official documentation.

Good luck

Answer (score 1):

You can use [SQL Alchamy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/) in python, and [lxml](http://lxml.de/) or the default [ElementTree](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) xml module for simple cases.

I have done both for a webservice I maintain, and they work nice.

You can also use a web development framework. I personally suggest [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) based on that it is a lightweight framework as opposted to [django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) for instance. However, depending on your exact use case the latter might be better.